# filling empty xml nodes with nodes from another xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Document 1 is full

```
<_Items>
    <_ItemName>COLOR REVOLUTION LIPSTICK</_ItemName>
    <_ItemQt>18300</_ItemQt>
    <_ItemNumber>1</_ItemNumber>
    <_Unit>шт</_Unit>
    <_ItemContract>
      <_ContractName>03011/1</_ContractName>
      <_ContractNumber>AA/001/2016</_ContractNumber>
      <_ContractDate>2016-11-24</_ContractDate>
    </_ItemContract>
    <_ItemCode>3304100000</_ItemCode>
    <_ItemCost>352529.07</_ItemCost>
    <_ItemPrice>1050.10</_ItemPrice>
  </_Items>
```

Document 2 is partially filled

```
<_Items>
    <_ItemName />
    <_ItemQt />
    <_Unit />
    <_ItemNumber />
    <_ItemContract>
      <_ContractName />
      <_ContractNumber />
      <_ContractDate />
    </_ItemContract>
    <_ItemCode />
    <_ItemCostNew>372338.46</_ItemCostNew>
    <_ItemCostOld>186169.21</_ItemCostOld>
    <_ItemPrice />
  </_Items>
```

So, how can i fill empty values in document 2 by same elements in document 1?
My idea is to delete all empty nodes in document 2

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(document2);
        xdoc.Descendants("Employee")
            .Where(e => e.Descendants().Any(d => String.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Value)))
            .Remove();
```

And then import all missing elements from document 1. But I don't know how to avoid overwriting of filled nodes

Answer (score 0):

simply iterate over your destination nodes, for each node check if it is empty or not, if not then get the value for it from the other node.

Comment: yes I thinking about this, but this method is too trivial and clumsy

Comment: if you have many nodes to iterate then you should think of another solution, but as long as you have few nodes to iterate then an easy, simple and working solution is enough

Comment: Okey, I ca iterate nodes in "Items" section with  foreach loop. But, some of them have childe nodes. How I can iterate them?